# make program also read from file instead of stdin

Tags: c

How do I change the following code so that it also goes through files instead of just stdin? 
For example the program would work if I do `./detag blah` where blah is a text file?

Do I use an if statement and try to `cat` it?

```
int main() {
   int in_tag = 0;
   char c;

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
       if (c == '<' || c == '>') {
           in_tag = (c == '<') ? 1 : 0;
       } else {
           if (!in_tag) {
               putchar(c);
           }
       }
   } }
```

Comment: do you want to file in/out operation?

Comment: You could have easily found multiple sources that solve your problem by simply Googling "c read input file". The first link explains input redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int in_tag = 0;
    char c;
    FILE *fp;


    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        perror("Error");
    }
    else{
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if (c == '<' || c == '>') {
                in_tag = (c == '<') ? 1 : 0;
            } else {
                if (!in_tag) {
                putchar(c);
                             }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
[12:43:24] wthom@dragon21:~/test [30] cat blah
this is a line in blah
this is a line in blah too
[12:43:26] wthom@dragon21:~/test [31] ./a.out blah
this is a line in blah
this is a line in blah too
```

Comment: Is it possible that it read from a file, and if the file doesnt exist, it read from stdin?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to change how you invoke it, and use redirection e.g.

```
$ ./detag < blah
```

will feed the contents of blah into your program via `stdin`, and consequently you don't need to change any code.

Otherwise you'll have to define `main()` using [argv and argv](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html). If you want it to process *multiple* files then this would be the approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the executable pointing `stdin` to a file.

Differently, from you code, you can use `fopen` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/ to open the file and `fgetc` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getc/ to read characters the same way you would do with `getchar`.

Close the file once you've done with `fclose`